# Different Ionic PWA home page vs web home page

Tags: manifest, progressive-web-apps, ionic4

I want my Ionic PWA home page to be different from website home page.

In `manifest.json` I tried changing `start_url` like this:

```
"start_url": "/sample/",
```

but that didn't work - what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Does it work after you uninstall and reinstall the PWA?